# How to select a particular text on the UI using selenium webdriver

Tags: html, selenium

I have a page on the UI where the data looks like this

name1                    label1
name2                    label2
name3                    label3
name4                    label4
name5                    label5
name6                    label6

If i have to look for name3 and also verify that label3 is adjacent to it? how would I do it?
the names have no id and name associated with them. checked in firebug.

the fir bug shows something like this:

```
<table class="content-grid" width="95%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr class="content-grid-stripe-light">
<td>name1 </td>
<td>
</tr>
<tr class="content-grid-stripe-dark">
</table>
```

Can someone please suggest.

Comment: Could you show the relevant part of the html containing `label3` and `name3`?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using selenium WebDriver, you can follow those steps:

1. use `tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tr/td"))` to put in `tablerows` all your `td` elements
2. fetch your tablerows and make a comapare between `tableRows[i]` and `tableRows[i+1]`, for example `if(tableRows.get(i).getText()).equals((tableRows.get(i+1).getText())) then .........`

Use something like that, I hope that this will be useful to you

Comment: Thanks For the suggesting. It helped.